# React and Ajax-запрос

Tags: ajax, reactjs

Начал изучать React и наткнулся на проблемму в своём небольшом проекте. (А точнее их 2).

1. После клика по кнопке поиск ( при введенном значение ) оно (введенное значение) отображается во втором инпуте и наоборот.
2. Так и не разобрался как отправить запрос после нажатия на button

   ```
   import React from "react";
   import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
   import Reflux from "reflux";

   import Header from "./Components/header.jsx";
   import Footer from "./Components/footer.jsx";
   import Map from "./Components/map.jsx";
   import MyStore from "./Store/mystore.jsx";
   import Actions from "./Actions/action.jsx"


   export class LondonTransport extends Reflux.Component{


       constructor(props){
           super(props);

           this.store = MyStore;
       }


       shouldComponentUpdate(){
           console.log("state Update");

           return true;
       }

       componentDidMount(){
           if (Actions.getType() == 'bus'){
               console.log('bus');
           } else {
               console.log('Stop Point');
           }

       }


       render(){
           return(
               <div>
                   <Header />
                   <div className ="content" >
                       <div className = "map">

                       </div>
                       <div className = "map-info">

                       </div>   
                       <div className="clear" ></div>         
                   </div>
                   <Footer emailAdress = "sdfsfs" />
               </div>
           )
       }
   }

   ReactDOM.render(<LondonTransport />, document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0]);
   ```

   Компонент Search

   ```
   import Reflux from "reflux";
   import React from "react";

   import Actions from "../Actions/action.jsx";
   import MyStore from "../Store/mystore.jsx";


   export default class Search extends Reflux.Component{

       constructor(){
           super();

           this.state = {
               inputData : ""
           }
           this.store = MyStore;
       }

       getInputData(e){
           this.setState({inputData : e.target.value})
       }

       handleSubmit(e){
          if (this.state.inputData){
              Actions.addInputData(this.state.inputData, this.props.type);
              this.setState({inputData : ""});
              Actions.showStore();
          } else {
              alert('Error input value!!!');
          }
       }


       render(){

           return(
               <form id="form_search_bus" >
                   <input type="search"  placeholder ={this.props.placeholder}
                       onChange = {this.getInputData.bind(this)} 
                       value = {this.state.inputData} />
                   <button type="button" 
                       onClick = {this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                           <i className = "fa fa-search"></i>
                   </button>
               </form>
           )
       }
   }
   ```

   Компонент Header

   ```
   import React from "react";

   import Search from "./search.jsx";


   export default function Header(){

       return(
           <header>
               <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
               <Search  
                   type ="bus" 
                   placeholder ="Введите номер автобуса" />
               <Search  
                   type ="stop-point" 
                   placeholder ="Введиет название остановки" />
               <Help />
           </header>
       )
   }
   ```

   Store

   ```
   import Reflux from "reflux";
   import Actions from "../Actions/action.jsx";

   export default class MyStore extends Reflux.Store{

       constructor(){
           super();
           this.state = {
               inputData : "",
               type : ""
           }

           this.listenTo(Actions.addInputData, this.onAddValue);
           this.listenTo(Actions.showStore, this.showDataFromStore);
           this.listenTo(Actions.getType, this.getType);
           this.listenTo(Actions.getInputValue, this.getInputValue);
       }

       onAddValue( inputValue, typeValue ){
           this.setState({inputData : inputValue});
           this.setState({type : typeValue});
       }

       showDataFromStore(){
           console.log(this.state);
       }

       getType(){
           return this.state.type;
       }

       getInputValue(){
           return this.state.inputData;
       }

   }
   ```

   index.html

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
       <title>London Transport Api</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="wrapper">

       </div>
       <script src="js/index.js" defer ></script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: Вы в `handleSubmit` этой строкой (`Actions.addInputData(this.state.inputData, this.props.type);`) меняете состояние, я правильно понял код?

Comment: Да и еще я здесь ни где не увидел никакого `ajax` запроса

Comment: Да, Вы правильно поняли, меняю состояние Store. Ajax-запрос не вставлял

Comment: Можно подробно немного что должно быть после клика? `ajax` вернет какой то контент и где вы этот контент внедрить хотите?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то он (ajax-запрос)  должен быть записан в componentDidMount()?

Comment: Вы должны менять состояние тогда когда уже у вас есть данные запроса `ajax`. `React` Смотрит и следит за состоянием `Virtual Dom` и когда оно меняется то он определяет как менять реальный `Dom` и меняет его. А вы сразу после клика уже меняете состояние. Вот и он меняет вашу страницу.

Comment: После клика я собираюсь сформировать url/ + input data  и отправить ajax-запрос. В зависимости от того, в какой из инпутов введено значение, будет формироваться свой url. полученные данные выводить через google api

Comment: Ну а почему вы не реализуйте запрос в методе `handleSearch` и там не делаете запрос? А после уже поменяете состояние.

Comment: Я Вас понял, уже этим и занимаюсь )

Comment: Ну как успехи? Получилось что то?

Comment: Да, все получается.

Comment: @Alex Если у Вас всё получилось поделитесь с сообществом в виде ответа

Comment: @RazGalstyan Вы бы могли оформить свои замечания/советы как ответ